# How to set fillColor and strokColor for path in swift

Tags: swift, uigraphicscontext, mkmapsnapshotter

I am getting image of certain area using `MKMapSnapshotter`.

I draw lines on the image using `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` to show polygon,

I can set the lines colour but I am unable to set fill color to the polygon.

Below is the code

```swift
private func drawLineOnImage(snapshot: MKMapSnapshotter.Snapshot, coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D]) -> UIImage {
    let image = snapshot.image

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(getMapFrameSize(), true, 0)

    image.draw(at: CGPoint.zero)

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    context!.setLineWidth(2.0)
    context!.setStrokeColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
    context!.move(to: snapshot.point(for: coordinates[0]))
    for i in 0...coordinates.count-1 {
        context!.addLine(to: snapshot.point(for: coordinates[i]))
        context!.move(to: snapshot.point(for: coordinates[i]))
    }
    context!.strokePath()
    context!.setFillColor(UIColor.green.cgColor)
    context!.fillPath()

    let resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return resultImage!
}
```

How can I achieve this?

**SOLUTION:**

```swift
private func drawLineOnImage(snapshot: MKMapSnapshotter.Snapshot, coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D]) -> UIImage {
    let image = snapshot.image

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(getMapFrameSize(), true, 0)

    image.draw(at: CGPoint.zero)

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

    context.setLineWidth(2.0)
    context.setStrokeColor(annotationColor.cgColor)
    context.setFillColor(annotationColor.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor)

    var coordinates = coordinates
    if let firstPoint = coordinates.first { context.move(to: snapshot.point(for: firstPoint)) }
    context.move(to: snapshot.point(for: coordinates[0]))
    coordinates.removeFirst()
    coordinates.forEach { context.addLine(to: snapshot.point(for: $0)) }

    context.drawPath(using: .fillStroke)
    context.fillPath()

    let resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return resultImage!
}
```

Comment: Your code shows you correctly settings both the stroke color and the fill color. What is your actual issue?

Comment: I want both border color and fill color, but unfortunately I am only getting border color. If I comment my border color code then I get fill color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs for `strokePath` and `fillPath`

> The current path is cleared as a side effect of calling this function.

That means that after calling `strokePath`, the path is cleared so there is noting to draw when you call `fillPath`

Instead you should call `context!.drawPath(using: .fillStroke)`

Comment: This did work though I had to make some changes to the drawing of lines.